# How can I add Masked Input Plugin on yet to be added contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, maskedinput

Is there a way to add [masked input plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) on dynamically loaded contents? something like `$("document").on("mask", "mask('(999) 999-9999')")`?

Currently Im using $.getScript(), but sometimes it fails to load at all...

Thanks!

Comment: You just need to ensure that when the dynamic content is added, you call `.mask` on the added input elements

Comment: @Brennan thats what Im currently doing, using `$.getScript('/js/masked.js');` to load the mask. However, the masked.js sometimes doesnt load making it unreliable. Is there a way maybe to make sure that $.getScript didnt fail?

Comment: Why are you using getScript and not just including your script in the head of the page?

Comment: Cause Im only loading a portion of the page.

Comment: But you can include the script in the head of whatever page you need to use the mask in. I'm not sure I follow the problem